# "In our tent are thousands of beetles". Is it correct?

Tags: grammar, there-is

Ran into the title sentence in a Babbel Learning French application. I would have said "In our tent there are thousands of beetles". Is it really possible to omit "there" here? Is it common? Are there any other examples where it is possible?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to omit "there" and not change the meaning of the sentence. But I think that most native BrE speakers would automatically include it. So you are far more likely to hear "*in our tent there are thousands of beetles*"

"In our tent are thousands of beetles" sounds almost biblical, for example see some of the older versions of [John 14:2](https://biblehub.com/john/14-2.htm)